# Send image file with wp_remote_post or "image":["The image must be an image.","The image must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg."]

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i am sending form data to an api all data send is corrected except image file.
but in response i get this message:
"image":["The image must be an image.","The image must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg."]

I guess form only send image name instead of image file.

this is my code;

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <div class="form-group"> <label  ><h3>Product Image</h3></label>&emsp; <input type="file" name="image" id="" required class="form-control">
</div><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="" class="button button-primary button-large" >
</form>

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           
           $Files = $_FILES['image'];
$url = 'my URL';
            $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
                'method'      => 'POST',
                'headers'     => array(
                    'Authorization'=> 'my token code',
                    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  
                    'timeout'     => 45,
                    'redirection' => 5,
                    'httpversion' => '1.0',
                    'blocking'    => true,
                ),
                'body'        => array(
                'image' =>  $_FILES['image']
                 ),
                'cookies'     => array()
                )
            );
```

Response:
"image":["The image must be an image.","The image must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, gif, svg."]

Note:
i am sending correct file in jpg format and light in size.

Comment: This is not enough information for being able to help you. Finding out why its not recognising the image is the first step. We are not mind readers, we can't help if we don't know what the actual problem is! "*I guess form only send image name instead of image file.*" Have you tried any debugged this to see what it is sending and if it *is* sending just the image name, instead of guessing?

Comment: its only send an image name.